# How to autofill repeating series in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to work out how to AutoFill the following data into Google Sheets.

```
| =A1 |  
| =B1 |  
| =C1 |  
| =A2 |  
| =B2 |  
| =C2 |  
| =A3 |  
| =B3 |  
| =C3 |
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

[Modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) helps, together with the [`offset`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379?hl=en) function:

```
=offset($A$1, (row(A1)-1)/3, mod(row(A1)-1, 3))
```

As written above, this formula is equivalent to `=A1` because both offset values are 0. But when it's copied down the column, it becomes

```
=offset($A$1, (row(A2)-1)/3, mod(row(A2)-1, 3))
```

which evaluates to `=offset($A$1, 1/3, 1)`, equivalent to `=B2`, because the offset is by 0 rows and 1 columns (fractional offsets are truncated to integer). Two rows down we get

```
=offset($A$1, (row(A4)-1)/3, mod(row(A4)-1, 3))
```

which is `=A2` because the offset is by 1 row and 0 columns.

Answer (score 0):

In the, perhaps unlikely, event that you want what you show you might copy down from Row1:

```
="="&char(65+mod(row()-1,3))&int((2+row())/3)
```

select the relevant column, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, then replace `=` with `=`.

This will extend the A,B,C series as A,B,C and the numeric to 4s, 5s, 6s ...

[CHAR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094120)
[MOD](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093497)
[ROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316)